# Refresh TabActivity on TabHost

Tags: java, android

I have same code:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity  {
private TabHost mTabHost;

private void setupTabHost() {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // create tabs and etc...
    setupTabHost();
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Category", "Category.class");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Top", "Top.class");
    setupTab(new TextView(this), "Favorite", "Favorite.class");

}

    private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag, final String className) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();    
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;   
            Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Category.class);
            if (className.equals("Category.class")) {
            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Category.class);}
            if (className.equals("Top.class")) {
                intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Top.class);}
            if (className.equals("Favorite.class")) {
            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Favorite.class);}


            TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(intent); {
            };
            mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
}


    private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}
```

I want create method on Category class like Refres() and if I tap on button on menu "Refresh"
This method wiil refresh data and view this on TabActivity.

Comment: `TabActivity` has been deprecated for well over two years. Please consider using a more modern tab implementation: action bar tabs, `FragmentTabHost`, `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, etc.

Comment: but, if i need 2.0 version Android app?

Comment: just use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP whereever you are starting the activity. You will get the refreshed screen in front of you.

Comment: you can ccall setupTabHost() on the refresh button... whats wrong in that?

Comment: @Narendra Pal If we add the flag, the activity will refresh every time I open its tab. Is there any way to refresh it at some particular action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was said in comments, TabActivity is deprecated and should not be used. If you need to support older devices, use [GrilledUI](https://github.com/Auxx/grilledui) library together with [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), which will do all the dirty work of supporting older devices.